# Reflect Arabic Word-Cloud

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-cloud, bidi, wordcloud2

This code run the huge data but with all Arabic words written in reverse:

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import os 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
os.chdir("C:")
f = open('example.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
data = arabic_reshaper.reshape(f.read())
WordCloud = WordCloud(font_path='arial',background_color='white', mode='RGB',width=2000,height=1000).generate(data)
plt.title("wordcloud")
plt.imshow(WordCloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

This is my data:

```
أحمد
خالد
سلمان
سليمان
عبدالله
عبدالرحمن
عبدالرحمن
خالد
صالح
```

Finally this what I get:

[image: WordCloud with Arabic in reverse]

Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more? What did you expect out of the algorithm?

Comment: What does `arabic_reshaper` do, and what happens when you omit that line, or just print the data before and after that operation? There might also be some hidden right-to-left mark in the text that's ignored by either python's `print`, or that `arabic_reshaper`, or the word-cloud generator. Have you tried reversing the strings "manually" using `s[::-1]`?

Comment: I expect out the Arabic words cloud but I get Arabic reverse words like the image above.

Comment: the **arabic_reshaper** not do any thing if i remove it will get same result.
about **s[::-1]** what line you think should add it ?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to import the arabic_resharper package then use get_display function and pass it to the wordcloud as the following:

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import arabic_reshaper # this was missing in your code

# os.chdir("C:")
f = open('example.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
data = arabic_reshaper.reshape(f.read())
data = get_display(data) # add this line
WordCloud = WordCloud(font_path='arial', background_color='white',
                  mode='RGB', width=2000, height=1000).generate(data)
plt.title("wordcloud")
plt.imshow(WordCloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Ok. Just created a tiny Arabic wrapper ([`ar_wordcloud`](https://github.com/iamaziz/ar_wordcloud)) to do this. I hope it helps.

`$ pip install ar_wordcloud`

```py
from ar_wordcloud import ArabicWordCloud
awc = ArabicWordCloud(background_color="white")

t = 'أهلاً وسهلا، اللغة العربية جميلة'
wc = awc.from_text(t)
```

[image]

---

Or, here is another example without the wrapper:

```py
from collections import Counter

from wordcloud import WordCloud          # pip install wordcloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt          
# -- Arabic text dependencies
from arabic_reshaper import reshape      # pip install arabic-reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display   # pip install python-bidi

rtl = lambda w: get_display(reshape(f'{w}'))

COUNTS = Counter("السلام عليكم ورحمة الله و بركاته السلام كلمة جميلة".split())
counts = {rtl(k):v for k, v in COUNTS.most_common(10)}

font_file = './NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf' # download from: https://www.google.com/get/noto
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path=font_file).generate_from_frequencies(counts)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Also, there is a PR discussion on this here: https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/pull/315

Answer (score 1):

Here is  a Good example on how you can generate Arabic wordCloud.

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display


reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf').generate(bidi_text)
wordcloud.to_file("worCloud.png")
```

Here is a link on how you can do it on : [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OmP1TOqXq8gCPNxlLCaKGWHNJ_q3dHRu?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution , converting an Arabic string to wordcloud using arworldcloud library

```
pip install ar_wordcloud
from ar_wordcloud import ArabicWordCloud
awc = ArabicWordCloud(font='NotoSansArabic-ExtraBold.ttf')
t = f"عيدفطر2020 سعيد، كل عام وانتم بخير"
awc.from_text(t).to_image()
```

reference: [for more details visit][1]
[1]: https://pypi.org/project/ar_wordcloud/